# Split method with line breaker vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I have a checkedlistbox to fill with the textbox values, but i have some issues cause if i paste the text from the textbox in a word file it comes with linebreakers, and not just spaces . Maybe that's why the checked list box is not being filled properly.

[image: Checkedlistbox and textbox]

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    Dim separated = TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine & " ")

    CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange(separated)
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove(vbCrLf)
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove("#")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove("PI")

End Sub
```

How can i get rid of this problem? If i paste the values in word they come like this:
[image: wordprintscreen]

Comment: So you want to take each item from the TextBox and it should appear in the ChecedListBox, is that right?  How are you expecting to divide up the items in the TextBox?  By lines?  Or each word separately?

Comment: Each word separately !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently separating the string where a space is followed by a new line.  Any other spaces around this string are included in the output.  You want to use a different version of Split, listing each character, so that ANY of those characters can be used to split the string:

```
Dim separated = TextBox2.Text.Split(vbCr, vbLf, vbTab, " "c)
```

This will treat one or more of space, tab, line feed OR carriage return as a split and will not include any of them in the strings it returns.  It will however return a number of empty strings, so you will need to add the strings individually, filtering these out.  The rest of the code can be replaced by this:

```
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each item In separated
        If item <> "" Then CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
```

Comment: You may also need to check for empty strings returned by Split.  I'll update

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse - Cleaner option then my suggestion.... forgot you can use vbTab directly.

Comment: Nice! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all spaces and then split

```
Dim separated = TextBox2.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(vbNewLine)
```

UPDATE to remove the tabs

```
char tabs = '\u0009';
Dim separated = TextBox2.Text.Replace(" ", "").Replace(tabs, "").Split(vbNewLine)
```

You need to remove all items that are not required prior to splitting.
SO... based on your example

```
char tabs = '\u0009';
StrippedText = TextBox2.Text.Replace(" ", "").Replace(tabs, "").Replace("P1" & vbCRLF & vbCRLF, "").Replace(vbCRLF & "#" & vbCRLF, "")
Dim separated = StrippedText.Split(vbNewLine)
```

Comment: I'm gonna use the other answer. But thanks anyway ! :)